# Prove a limit involving the ceiling function

Tags: number-theory, limits, irrational-numbers, ceiling-and-floor-functions

I found a pattern that I want to prove:

> $$f(x) = 2^{\lceil \log_2(3^x)\rceil} - 3^x\quad \{x\in\mathbb{Z}^+\} $$
>   $$ \lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} f(x) = \infty $$

Discussion:

$$ f(x) = 2^{\lceil \log_2(3^x)\rceil} - 3^x = 3^x(2^{\lceil \log_2(3^x)\rceil-\log_2(3^x)}-1)$$

$$0<\lceil \log_2(3^x)\rceil-\log_2(3^x)<1\ \Rightarrow\ 0<f(x)<3^x$$

$f(x)$'s lower bound is zero and its upper bound tends to infinity. As far as I know, $f(x)$ can oscillate anywhere in between. However, after checking a few first thousands values of $f$, I am convinced that the function indeed tends to infinity. I guess the fact that $x$ is an integer plays a role in that.

If $\lceil \log_2(3^x) \rceil$ was really close to $\log_2(3^x)$, $f(x)$ would be really close to $0$, so the limit would not hold. Experimental results suggest the limit exists, so I guess there are some restrictions on how close $\log_2(3^x)$ can be to its ceiling integer.

I don't know how to proceed from that.

Comment: @abiessu Formally, a function goes to $\infty$ has no limit, if that what you're talking about; however, I guess you understand what I mean by $f(x) \rightarrow \infty$.

Comment: Btw +1 for the nice question.

Comment: @FelixFourcolor: a function that goes to $\infty$ has that limit.  A function that goes to multiple values repeatedly without converging to just one does not have a limit.

Comment: @abiessu I guess it's the matter of convention. However if that's the case, I don't understand your previous comment.

Comment: https://oeis.org/A063003

Comment: Do you know of Terence Tao's blog? He has a nice discussion of this problem at https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2011/08/25/the-collatz-conjecture-littlewood-offord-theory-and-powers-of-2-and-3/ . From proposition 6 and 7 follows your conjecture immediately. There is another page there where the Baker's formulae are more detailed explicated showing also proofs but unfortunately I don't remember the url ...

Comment: Ahh, I found the other page https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2011/08/21/hilberts-seventh-problem-and-powers-of-2-and-3/ There is corollary 4 from where a proof for your conjecture follows immediately.